# Logic against a set list staring from the end

Tags: python

I have a set within a list from another part of a program. Looks like: `[('esdfdf.com', 3), ('sdsfdfd.com', 2)...]`. Basically I am trying to put the list in a for loop and just take the domains that have a 3 or higher. The problem I think I'm having is I am referencing the overall length starting from the right. This is important because there could be numbers in the domain so if it starts looking from the end of the string, It should solve this.

I have tried it this way that, without the remove statement seems to reference the actual list item. Then I've tried using length but that gave me the overall length of a portion i think.

```
    qData = list(set([row for row in get]))

for x in qData:
    If qData[-2] == 1 or qData[-2] == 2:
        qData.remove(x)
    else:
        qData =+ qData[x]
return qData
```

Happy Path: It takes the list of domain and number and looks for ones that have 1 or 2 and takes them out of the list. So when it returns, its just things higher than 2.

Error messages: Incorrect referencing and within the string.

Comment: Is this really a list of sets?  Are you sure they aren't tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of all items in qData, where x[1] >= 3, using this statement:

```py
qData = [('esdfdf.com', 3), ('sdsfdfd.com', 2)]
filteredQData = [x for x in qData if x[1] >= 3]
print(filteredQData) #[[('esdfdf.com', 3)]
```

Comment: Oh man, I didn't realize that you could do x for x. That's actually really cool